# JavaScript/Html - onclick variable as arg1?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to get a value inside into an onclick event.

```
<a href="#" onclick="ChatRequest('id','{session.member_id}');"
```

Secondaryid has a value
But firstid not. I get only the name not a value.
Have anyone Advice for me.

```
function setConversation(id) {
  conversation_partner = id;
  $('#conv_messages_list').html(getConvLoader());
  $('#conv_member_list li').removeClass('active');
  $('#conv_partner_'+id).addClass('active');
  $('#conv_members').addClass('hidden-xs');
  $('#conv_messages, #conv_dd').removeClass('hidden-xs');
  getMessages(id,0);
}
```

Comment: Please add some more code. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: with quotes it's a string, not a variable. The fact that the 2nd param works is due to {}, also does not require string.

Comment: Also, if your 2nd parameter is working, just copy that logic to the first one ;)

Comment: so you want to pass string in 1st and a variable in second parameter? fine but show some code regarding secondaryid

Comment: Hi, i need the Firstid from a chat javascript the secondary is from a other javscript and has the value.
I add the function form 1st script to get the id

Comment: Seems like you're trying to pass variables inside quotes converting their names into strings. Maybe this is what you try to achieve : `<a href="#" onclick="ChatRequest(id, session.member_id);"`

Comment: with {} on first value it works not , without  Quotes the onclick works not anymore no popup then.

Answer (score 0):

Merging two javascripts and this code works arg1 witout quotes.
Thanks all for giving hints.

```
<a href="#" onclick="ChatRequest(id,'{session.member_id}');"
```